# Javascript: Class Design Pattern - pseudo-polymorphism

Tags: javascript, polymorphism

In Kyle Simpson's **You-Don't-Know-Js** books series while discussing the class pattern implementation in pre-es6 javascript in **this & Object Prototypes** book of the series he mentioned in chapter 4 what he called **[pseudo-polymorphism](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/you-dont-know/9781491905142/ch04.html)**.

He described this pseudo-polymorphism saying:

> But because of JavaScript's peculiarities, explicit pseudo-polymorphism (because of shadowing!) creates brittle manual/explicit linkage in every single function where you need such a (pseudo-)polymorphic reference. This can significantly increase the maintenance cost. Moreover, while explicit pseudo-polymorphism can emulate the behavior of "multiple inheritance", it only increases the complexity and brittleness.

From what i could understand here, This pseudo-polymorphism is a bad behavior that we better avoid because of the explicit calling for the *SUPER* class like in his example about calling *Vehicle* class from inside of *Car* class so we would do this as an explicit call like this :

```
function Car () {
    Vehicle.call( this );
}
//also overriding Vehicle's methods
Car.prototype.methodName = function( p1 ) {
    //manipulate p1 then call the super method. 
    Vehicle.prototype.methodName.call( this, p1 );
};
```

But i am wondering if the problem here is related to the explicit use of *Vehicle* class name then why we don't just do this :

```
function Car () {
    this.super = Object.getPrototypeOf( this ).constructor;
    this.super.call( this );
}
//also overriding Vehicle's methods
Car.prototype.methodName = function( p1 ) {
    //manipulate p1 then call the super method. 
    this.super.prototype.methodName.call( this, p1 );
};
```

Isn't this kind of faking or emulating the *super* keyword in other class-oriented-languages which solving the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...why we don't just do this...

Because it doesn't work, but you're **far** from the first person to fall down that trap. :-) Try adding a `LuxuryCar` subclass of `Car` to see the problem: Now `this.super` (even in `Car` code) refers to `Car`, not `Vehicle`.

There are patterns that make it possible to avoid explicitly using the name `Vehicle` in `Car` in ES5-level code (I [wrote one of them up in 2009](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2009/09/simple-efficient-supercalls-in.html)), but they're obsolete now; instead, we use `class` syntax from ES2015 (transpiling if necessary):

```js
class Vehicle {
    methodName() {
        console.log("Vehicle#methodName");
    }
}
class Car extends Vehicle {
    methodName() {
        super.methodName();
        console.log("Car#methodName");
    }
}
class LuxuryCar extends Car {
    methodName() {
        super.methodName();
        console.log("LuxuryCar#methodName");
    }
}

const l = new LuxuryCar();
l.methodName();
```

Comment: yes thank you, i didn't think about this subclass point but now its clear :)

Comment: Right, the `[[HomeObject]]` didnt exist in pre ES6 which actually enables `super` ...